# opengl ray-tracing simulation program by celeste fowler non-windows version

Tags: opengl

In the '90 SGI published a program "backtrace" to simulate ray tracing by celeste fowler. I have only the version ported to Windows NT. 
Does someone know where to find an other version? I am using freeglut and MESA under linux.

Comment: [?](https://web.archive.org/web/20001008105727/http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/tpl/cgi-bin/getdoc.cgi?coll=0620&db=man&fname=/usr/share/catman/u_man/cat6/backtrace.z)

Answer (score 0):

I started to adapted the program to freeglut and MESA. I hope to present the program in some weeks.